# Understanding a Golang panic

Tags: go

I have some Golang code that is, very intermittently (once every few hours), resulting in a panic and I need some guidance understanding how to find the cause.  The code is this (with line numbers):

```
audio-process.go:

    var MyChannel chan<- interface{}
    var newDatagramList = list.New()

    func operateAudioProcessing() {
        var channel = make(chan interface{})
        MyChannel = channel
        newDatagramList.Init()
        ...
415     go func() {
416        for cmd := range channel {
417            switch msg := cmd.(type) {
418                 case *MyThing:
419                 {
420                     newDatagramList.PushBack(msg)
421                 }
422             }
423         }
424     }()
425 }
```

...and the panic occurs when `newDatagramList.PushBack()` is called at line 420.  The code sending into this channel is:

```
audio-in.go:

    thing := new(MyThing)
    ...
    MyChannel <- thing
```

...and, to complete the picture, there is a separate timed `go func()` which processes `newDatagramList` as follows:

```
go func() {
    var next *list.Element
    for _ = range processTicker.C {
        for newElement := newDatagramList.Front(); newElement != nil; newElement = next {
            next = newElement.Next();
            myProcessingFunction(newElement.Value.(*MyThing))
            newDatagramList.Remove(newElement)
        }
}
```

The panic output is:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x5702d1]

goroutine 12 [running]:
panic(0x76e520, 0xc82000e100)
/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
container/list.(*List).PushBack(0xc820054e40, 0x6c4f80, 0xc827294e20, 0xc8273e0b01)
/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/container/list/list.go:139 +0x1c1
main.operateAudioProcessing.func2(0xc8200164e0, 0xc82000f310, 0xc820024078, 0x240)
/home/rob/gocode/src/audio-process.go:420 +0x58b
created by main.operateAudioProcessing
/home/rob/gocode/src/audio-process.go:442 +0x5ba
```

Which thing is the panic telling me is at fault here? There was no complaint about the allocation and send into the channel in the first place, so I don't see how that can be wrong.  `newDatagramList` is clearly initialised (and the channel has been running and receiving messages for some time).

How do I go about determining what's making me go bang?

Comment: The panic I think is saying that the problem is inside the Pushback method in the list package. Bit suspicious that newDatagramList is a package global. Could be a race condition as list isn't threadsafe - is newDatagramList accessed from another goroutine?

Comment: You could give your app a spin with `go run -race` to see if you have data races.

Comment: Ooo err, I'd not twigged that `container/list` isn't threadsafe, that could certainly cause an issue as there's a `for range {}` timed loop that processes the elements and moves them out.  All add a mutex and see if that fixes it.

Comment: https://golang.org/src/container/list/list.go?s=3579:3626#L128 doesn't look to be any syncronization on `container/list List at all

Comment: @Rob how many go routines are you spawning that access `PushBackList`?

Comment: There is only one `PushBack()` operation on `newDatagramList`, the one you see above.  The other operations on `newDatagramList`, all in the separate timed `go func()`, are `Front()`, `Next()` and, maybe critically, `Remove()`.  `Remove()` happens after the datagram has been processed in the timed `go func()`.

Comment: I wonder if the `go func()` loop might be attempting to process and remove a half-added item?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the root cause is `container/list` access are not threadsafe and `Remove()`  and `PushBack`/`Front`/`Next` create a race condition because of unsynchronized access https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.6/src/container/list/list.go#L110

Comment: Could you please post the full code where you are scheduling the `Remove()` ?

Comment: Original post updated to include the timed `go func()` code.

Comment: @Rob, FTR, no data structure in go is safe for concurrent read+write without synchronization. Methods which allow concurrent use are documented as such, but it wouldn't make sense to document every single other method in the standard library as not being safe for concurrent use.

Comment: @JimB: understood now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The panic stack:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x5702d1]

goroutine 12 [running]:
panic(0x76e520, 0xc82000e100)
/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
container/list.(*List).PushBack(0xc820054e40, 0x6c4f80, 0xc827294e20, 0xc8273e0b01)
/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/container/list/list.go:139 +0x1c1
main.operateAudioProcessing.func2(0xc8200164e0, 0xc82000f310, 0xc820024078, 0x240)
/home/rob/gocode/src/audio-process.go:420 +0x58b
created by main.operateAudioProcessing
/home/rob/gocode/src/audio-process.go:442 +0x5ba
```

Is saying that an "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" is occurring at the top listed frame

```
 container/list.(*List).PushBack(0xc820054e40, 0x6c4f80, 0xc827294e20, 0xc8273e0b01)
```

On

```
 /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/container/list/list.go:139 +0x1c1
```

Which looks to be [from godoc](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.6/src/container/list/list.go#L139)

```
// PushBack inserts a new element e with value v at the back of list l and returns e.
func (l *List) PushBack(v interface{}) *Element {
    l.lazyInit()
    return l.insertValue(v, l.root.prev)
}
```

---

This is cool since it's in this frame it looks to be erroring on `l.root.prev`

The datatype that is being built on `container/list` is completely unsynchronized and there are many interleaving of go routines that could result in an in-between state where list element pointers are being added removed at the same time.

For example `remove` has many different operations:

```
func (l *List) remove(e *Element) *Element {
    e.prev.next = e.next
    e.next.prev = e.prev
    e.next = nil // avoid memory leaks
    e.prev = nil // avoid memory leaks
    e.list = nil
    l.len--
    return e
}
```

---

If this was executed synchronously there wouldn't be an issue but because multiple go routines are operating on it.

Suppose we have an element `E`, with a pointer to a previous and a next, and two goroutines acting on it

```
PREV - E - NEXT  

GOROUTINE1                                           GOROUTINE2

READ - E.PREV returns element (E2) with `NEXT` -> E

                                                    REMOVE(E) is called
                                                    e.next = nil // avoid memory leaks

E2.NEXT.NEXT access occurs now Nil!!! 
resulting in panic
```

Comment: I suppose this tells us something about how Golang implements channels and `go func()`: for the problem to occur `PushBack()` must be happening right in the middle of `Remove()` (I think), so these are not dumb loops, it's proper threading.  Data is arriving every 20 ms and the `go func()` process loop is running every 20 ms yet it takes an hour or two (so several million events) for the problem to occur.  Anyway, I expect a mutex will solve it. Probably the Golang guys should state that `container/list` isn't threadsafe as a warning to others. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Rob !!! Yes!! I was googling for thread safety in their godoc.  I'm surprised they don't explicitly mention it too

Comment: I've added a documentation issue for them on Github.

Comment: ...[here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25105) but they don't think it's necessary as most of Golang's C-like functions are similarly not thread safe.  Just need to remember that in many ways Golang is a parser in front of good-ole C.  And that's a strength, just mustn't forget.

Comment: Confirmed that after 3 hours of running with `sync.Lock()/Unlock()` protection the problem has not recurred.